# Add target=”_blank”

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm trying to add target _blank with keeping link title?

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/" title="Go to W3Schools HTML section">Visit our HTML Tutorial</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title`s and `target`s aren't mutually exclusive - just add the target in there:

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/" title="Go to W3Schools HTML section" target="_blank">Visit our HTML Tutorial</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add target=“_blank” after your title attribute.